# How to grab values years dynamically in Oracle/SQL depending on whether they are available (not Null) or not (Null)

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say that I have a table that has a person with their weight by year.

```
 NAME     2012        2013       2014         2015        2016         2017      2018         2019
JOHN      180          185       192          205         199          198       193          null
MIKE      190          191       191          195         195          195       195          195
```

What I am trying to do is grab an min/max of the last NON NULL years. (as shown in the result set below)

```
NAME     MIN         MAX
JOHN     192         205
MIKE     195         195
```

Below is what I've tried, is there a better way to do this?

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN 2019 IS NULL
         AND 2018 > 2017 > 2016 > 2015 > 2014
         THEN 2018
         WHEN 2019 IS NULL
         AND 2017 > 2016 > 2015 > 2014 > 2018
         THEN 2017
         WHEN 2019 IS null
         AND 2016 > 2017 > 2018 > 2015 > 2014
         THEN 2016
         WHEN 2019 IS NULL
         AND 2015 > 2018 > 2017 > 2016 > 2014
         THEN 2015
         WHEN 2019 IS NULL
         AND 2014 > 2018 > 2017 > 2016 > 2015
         THEN 2014
         WHEN 2019 IS NOT NULL
         AND 2019 > 2018 > 2017 > 2016 > 2015 > 2014
         THEN 2019
         WHEN 2019 IS NOT NULL
         AND 2018 > 2017 > 2016 > 2015 > 2014 > 2018
         THEN 2018
         WHEN 2019 IS NOT null
         AND 2017 > 2017 > 2018 > 2015 > 2014 > 2019
         THEN 2017
         WHEN 2019 IS NOT NULL
         AND 2016> 2015 > 2018 > 2017 > 2019 > 2014
         THEN 2016
         WHEN 2019 IS NOT NULL
         AND 2015 > 2014 > 2018 > 2017 > 2016 > 2019
         THEN 2015
         WHEN 2019 IS NOT NULL
         AND 2014 > 2015 > 2015 > 2018 > 2017 > 2016 > 2019
         THEN 2014
          END                                  as MAX
```

Thanks in advance
        FROM Table
       WHERE

Comment: Is that how your data is actually set up? With each year being a column?

Comment: This is a really bad database design. You should only have three columns in that table: name, weight, year - not one column for each year. With a properly normalized data model, this would be a very easy query: `select name, min(weight), max(weight) from the_table group by name`;

Comment: yeah unfortunately so :( This is a very simpliied version of the issue

Comment: can we use something like the greatest function?

Comment: What if multiple years are NULL, e.g. 2018 and 2019?

Comment: then we are going to want 2017, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table design is not optimal, and it would be best to normalize it get each weight per year on a separate *record*, instead of column.  That being said, if you must continue, one trick you can do is to use `COALESCE` to replace a `NULL` column weight with -1.  This will effectively take it out of the picture.  Then, use the scalar `GREATEST` function to find the legitimate maximum:

```
SELECT
    GREATEST(COALESCE("2019", -1),
             COALESCE("2018", -1),
             COALESCE("2017", -1),
             COALESCE("2016", -1),
             COALESCE("2015", -1),
             COALESCE("2014", -1),
             COALESCE("2013", -1),
             COALESCE("2012", -1)) AS max_weight
FROM yourTable;
```

Note: In the off chance that *every* column might be `NULL`, then the above call to `GREATEST` would return -1.  In this case, you can either leave that value there as a market for no valid data, or you could wrap in a `CASE` expression and replace with some other value.

Comment: Thanks. Here's the curveball though. if 2019 is null, we only want to calculate the max from 2018-2013. if 2019 is available only 2019-2014. do you know how we can do this?

Comment: I'm not going to even attempt swinging at that curve ball :-) ... you should fix your table design.  Even with a correct setup, your new requirement would be fairly non trivial, and would have us all stumped for at least a few minutes.

Comment: To second @TimBiegeleisen 's comment, the reason(s) we are suggesting fixing the design because A) it is nearly impossible for us to meet all of your requirements with the design as it stands and B) the way to do it, as Tim has said, is with a bunch of `CASE..WHEN` (`if...`) statements that do not truly provide a repeatable, robust solution.

Comment: thanks guys. unfortunately I have little say in my table design :( i'll imlpement the case method!

Answer (score 2):

Greatest() and Least() functions would help in this case

Greatest() function compares the columns and provide maximum value from those columns and Least() function provide minimum value from those columns.

```
     select name,
             LEAST(2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018) as MIN_WEIGHT
            , GREATEST(2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018) as MAX_WEIGHT
     from your_table
     /
```

Comment: Is there any way to grab the max from the last 5 available years? so if 2019 is null, then 2014-2018 but if 2019 isn not null then 2015-2019? Thanks by the way.

Comment: Seems something odd requirement. If you are sure that value of 2019 will be null or not null then you can try decode() function.....`Select name,
     DECODE(2019, NULL, LEAST(2014,2015,2016,2017,2018),GREATEST(2015,2016,2017,2018,2019) ) as MIN_WEIGHT,
     DECODE(2019, NULL, GREATEST(2014,2015,2016,2017,2018),GREATEST(2015,2016,2017,2018,2019) ) as MAX_WEIGHT
from your_table
/`

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your remark on Tim's answer

> if 2019 is null, we only want to calculate the max from 2018-2013. if
>   2019 is available only 2019-2014

you want min/max over 6 years.

The easiest way is to normalize the data first using `UNPIVOT`, by default this removes NULLs:

```
SELECT NAME, weight, yr,
   Row_Number() Over (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY yr DESC) AS rn
FROM mytable
UNPIVOT(weight
    FOR yr
    IN (
        y2012 as 2012
       ,y2013 as 2013
       ,y2014 as 2014
       ,y2015 as 2015
       ,y2016 as 2016
       ,y2017 as 2017
       ,y2018 as 2018
       ,y2019 as 2019
    )
)
```

Then you apply your logic using Windowed Aggregates to return the last 6 years only. Using `row_number` you get the last 6 **rows**

```
WITH cte AS 
 (
    SELECT NAME, weight, yr,
       Row_Number() Over (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY yr DESC) AS rn
    FROM mytable
    UNPIVOT(weight
        FOR yr
        IN (
            y2012 as 2012
           ,y2013 as 2013
           ,y2014 as 2014
           ,y2015 as 2015
           ,y2016 as 2016
           ,y2017 as 2017
           ,y2018 as 2018
           ,y2019 as 2019
        )
    )
 )
SELECT NAME, Min(weight), Max(weight), Min(yr), Max(yr)
FROM cte
WHERE rn BETWEEN 1 AND 6
GROUP BY NAME
```

Using `max` you get the rows from the last 6 **years** (which will return a different result if there are additional NULLs):

```
WITH cte AS 
 (
   SELECT NAME, weight, yr, 
      Max(yr) Over (PARTITION BY NAME) AS maxyr
    FROM mytable
    UNPIVOT(weight
        FOR yr
        IN (
            y2012 as 2012
           ,y2013 as 2013
           ,y2014 as 2014
           ,y2015 as 2015
           ,y2016 as 2016
           ,y2017 as 2017
           ,y2018 as 2018
           ,y2019 as 2019
        )
    )
 )
SELECT NAME, Min(weight), Max(weight), Min(yr), Max(yr)
FROM cte
WHERE yr BETWEEN maxyr -5 AND maxyr
GROUP BY NAME
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6f1afe551d5a89561b999009e5d03dd9)

Comment: thanks. what about the edge case where 2019 is not null but 2018 is?

Comment: @JohnWick e.g. `2010,2011,2012,2013,null, 2015,2016,2017,null,2019`  #1 will always try to sum up 6 **rows** with data, i.e. 2012 to 2019, ignoring 2014 and 2018 = **8 years**, #2 will sum 6 years, 2019-5 = 2014 to 2019, but 2018 is missing = **5 rows**. A `COUNT` shows the number of years with data